# jquery accessing newly loaded dom elements

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom

i have a simple form to load dynamically some items from my database

```
<input type="text" name="search" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

when i click the submit button my DOM will append something like

```
<ul>
  <li class="name">item1</li>
  <li class="quantity">120</li>
  <li class="update"><input type="text" name="update_quantity" /></li>
  <li class="submit_quantity"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="update"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="name">item2</li>
  <li class="quantity">14</li>
  <li class="update"><input type="text" name="update_quantity" /></li>
  <li class="submit_quantity"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="update"></li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="name">item3</li>
  <li class="quantity">13</li>
  <li class="update"><input type="text" name="update_quantity" /></li>
  <li class="submit_quantity"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="update"></li>
</ul>
```

i have a php that does all the logic that i need: to display the items, to update the quantity, to display the quantity

so i want to access the newly loaded DOM elements and when i insert a quantity in the text field for each item and then when i press the submit button to dynamically load the new stock value and display it in the quantity list item.

i did it in the traditional way, accessing the DOM elements after loading them

```
$.ajax({
        url:php file url",
        type:'post',
        cache:false,
        data:'input='+field,
        success:function(data){

                       //access each element with $.each(

                           for each current item add an .click(

                                call an ajax function to update the quantity and display the new quantity
                            )
                       )


                    }
})
```

all fine but when i load the page i want to display the current stock and then apply all that that i have described above, and something looks wrong, it looks that i repeat to much code, the code it is too far from being neat.

i did some research and it looks like i have to use an .on() event handler, but i ca't use it for the initial page load. I need some help to guide my way, some articles some good material to guide me.

from what i have read there is a way to store some of my query functions in variables and combining those with .on()

Answer (score 1):

There's a jQuery plugin, [livequery](https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery) which may be helpful to you. LiveQuery gives you the ability to connect to your elements as you would normally with jQuery, but in the event that new elements are added it will automatically attach the defined behaviors without any additional management on your end.

In order to wire up your event handling for the elements, you may have to wait until the DOM is ready, you can do this by adding your jQuery code in a domReady callback, e.g.

```
$(document).domReady(function() {
   ...
});
```

**Edit:** As pointed out by another user in the comments below, apparently jQuery's built in [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) also hooks into dynamically added elements, similar to LiveQuery mentioned above.

Comment: @ War10ck, but how to use .on() on both situations, on page load and when the DOM is altered ?, so the page loads with current stock (just php no query needed)...but then i want to apply ajax actions to both default loaded (php way) and the ajax added content. to what event to bind the function that loads the current item stock ?

Comment: You may have to make sure your jQuery code runs in a `domReady` callback to make sure that all of the DOM content is available before you begin wiring up using either `.livequery()` or `.on()`. See above edit.

Comment: tried a simple example, did a button .on function to alert something and than an ajax example to dynamically load some more buttons but the action applies just to the originally loaded button